# Alfresco custom property (via type's mandatory aspect) not exposed by CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I defined a new type in Alfresco with a mandatory aspect `zhx:rm` that defines a property `zhx:taskNo`.

I created a document of this type, and set its `zhx:taskNo` value.

Using OpenCMIS Workbench 0.10.0, I opened the properties of this document.

**PROBLEM:** `zhx:taskNo` is not shown.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is it Alfresco's intended behavior?
While CMIS Extensions might be a solution, I don't want to use them, as it would make the code less manageable.

```
<types>
   <type name="zhx:rm">
      <title>RM</title>
      <parent>cm:content</parent>
      <mandatory-aspects>
         <aspect>zhx:rmAspect</aspect>
      </mandatory-aspects>
   </type>
</types>

<aspects>
   <aspect name="zhx:rmAspect">
      <title>RM Aspect</title>
      <properties>
         <property name="zhx:taskNo">
            <type>d:text</type>
            <index enabled="true">
               <atomic>true</atomic>
               <stored>true</stored>
               <tokenized>both</tokenized>
            </index>
         </property>
      </properties>
   </aspect>
</aspects>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original post said you created a new type. If you created a new custom type, this does not require CMIS 1.1 to work. The custom type should show up in the types list and the custom properties (if they were set) should show up in the properties list.

You should be able to set the properties in Workbench if they have not already been set.

A good example is the cmiscustom:document type. You can create an object of that type and set some of its properties and you will see them in the workbench property list.

If you are talking about aspects, you must use the CMIS 1.1 binding to see the properties that are defined as part of the aspect. To use the CMIS 1.1 binding, make sure that you are using the following service URL, assuming you are using AtomPub:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

I have confirmed that, using this binding, custom properties defined in an aspect show up in the properties list within Workbench 0.10.0.

Comment: Thanks! They really don't appear in Workbench, though. I just noticed that the problem occurs **only for properties of mandatory aspects**, not for direct properties nor inherited properties. I pasted my model for clarity.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Your original post said "type" but now that you've clarified, I see that the property missing in the Workbench is defined in an aspect. You won't see aspect defined properties in Workbench using the CMIS 1.0 endpoints.

Comment: I've clarified my answer based on your clarification of the original question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for the confusion, I did not know about this different URL, interesting!

Comment: Sure, no problem. You might also be interested in this blog post, which covers the new URLs as well as a few other CMIS related changes in 4.2: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2013/09/15/3554